# How do you merge two Git repositories with GIT Extentions?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I'm using "GIT Extensions" to manage my git repositories,
does someone knows how to merge two different repositories with this tool?
is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Git Extensions is a UI for git. So the question you need to ask yourself "How do I merge two repos in git". And then explain what exactly you mean by that.

Comment: @RussKie thx, but I know there are lots of ways to do it with git, I wanted to know if I can do it via Git Extensions in an easy way 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

For example, if you want to add REPO2 into REPO1 you can do it in this way:

1. Open REPO1 and add REPO2 as remote repository (add name and remote url and save)

   [image]
2. After that you will see a different branch/line detached from your ORIGIN/MASTER. Now you can merge the new BRANCH/REPO2 into your ORIGIN/MASTER REPO1.

   [image]